# How to be greedy but not so greedy?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Is there a way, using just regular expressions, to extract 1.jpg and xx.jpg (ie just the file names after the last /) from this string:

```
"...<img src='/can/be/.../anything/1.jpg'> ... <img src='/unknown/.../path/xx.jpg'>.."
```

Comment: Try `[^\/]+\.jpg` to get the jpg file names, followed by `/`

Comment: In what language? use global modifier to get all the matches. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rG6aV5/1)

Comment: Python 3 and PowerShell.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/6

Comment: Nice question title and display pic :-) (Y)

Comment: What `...` represents ? are there any similar <img> tags in between and you want to skip them ?

Comment: Thanks to all. `src=.*?([^\/]+\.jpg)` works for me.

Comment: @NeverHopeless `...` means any amount of text with unknown pattern.  So are `can/be/anything` and `unknown/path`.

Answer (score 0):

Below regex will help you:

```
[\w\d]+\.jpg
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL9aP8/1)